# Changing property of an object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, setinterval

Hi i am trying to refresh the value of a property inside an object after delay of one second i am using setInterval function for that purpose but value of the property i get is not right

```
            var nextlvl = '';
            function showPlaybackData() {

                            if(j.nextLevel == -1){

                                nextlvl = '';

                            }else if(j.nextLevel == 0){

                                nextlvl = '240p';

                            }else if(j.nextLevel == 1){

                                nextlvl = '360p';

                            }else if(j.nextLevel == 2){

                                nextlvl = '480p';

                            }else if(j.nextLevel == 3){

                                nextlvl = '720p';

                            }else if(j.nextLevel == 4){

                                nextlvl = '1080p';

                            }
                            console.log(nextlvl);
                            return nextlvl;

                        }

                var g = {
                    id: -1,
                    label: 'auto(' + setInterval( showPlaybackData , 1000) +')',
                    selected: -1 === j.manualLevel
                };
                e.push(g)
```

the property label's value should be one of these resolutions i am setting according to condition but it shows 14 or 18 or 15. any solution to that?
when i use `console.log` i get accurate value within the function but when i call the function in `setInterval` the value is not right.

Comment: That's not how you use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Return_value) - it doesn't return the value of the `showPlaybackData` function as you seem to expect.

Comment: `setInterval` does not return the desired value. `setInterval` returns a number which is used to keep track of the timer. You need given more data of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @KarlReid how can i get desired data any solution to that?

Comment: @Panther can you please explain a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to refactor the code so that you use `nextlvl` within the function, instead of returning it. It's difficult to answer without seeing your full code, but something like this :

```
var j = ....
var e = [];
var g = {
    id: -1,
    selected: -1 === j.manualLevel
};
function showPlaybackData() {
    var nextlvl = '';
    if(j.nextLevel == 8){
        nextlvl = '';
    }else if(j.nextLevel == 0){
        nextlvl = '240p';
    }else if(j.nextLevel == 1){
        nextlvl = '360p';
    }else if(j.nextLevel == 2){
        nextlvl = '480p';
    }else if(j.nextLevel == 3){
        nextlvl = '720p';
    }else if(j.nextLevel == 4){
        nextlvl = '1080p';
    }
    console.log(nextlvl);
    g.label = 'auto(' + nextlvl +')';
    e.push(g);
};

setInterval(showPlaybackData, 1000);
```

As a note, you should consider looking at [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statements, if you're not aware of them, as an alternative to the `if/else`s.

Answer (score 0):

setInterval returns an identifier that allows you to retrieve (and, for example, clear) the timer, rather than the result of the function. Rather than returning the value you want in the function that's looped, you'll need to set a value in an object whose scope you have access to from within that loop.

Comment: can you please share an example how can i achieve what i am trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

May be this works for you :

```
function showPlaybackData(jpassed) {                    
                        var nextlvl = '';
                        switch(jpassed.nextLevel) {
                            case '':
                                      nextlvl = '';
                                      break;
                            case '240p':
                                      nextlvl = '240p';
                                      break;
                            case '360p':
                                      nextlvl = '360p';
                                      break;
                            case '480p':
                                      nextlvl = '480p';
                                      break;
                            case '720p':
                                      nextlvl = '720p';
                                      break;
                            case '1080p':
                                      nextlvl = '1080p';
                                      break;
                            default:
                                // any default logic
                        }
                        console.log(nextlvl);
                        return nextlvl;
}
```

And then update your object inside setinterval :

```
var j = ...
var g = {
             id: -1,
             label:'',
             selected: -1 === j.manualLevel
         };
setInterval(function(){
                          g.label = 'auto(' +showPlaybackData(j)+')' ;
                          e.push(g)                              
                    },2000,j,showPlaybackData,g);
```

@Karl Reid : Thanx Karl, I've updated the answer.

Comment: How does this help? The value of `nextlvl` is still lost in the ether since it can't be returned, so there's no point calling the function at all...